# Why does Bash evaluate my variable expansion I stored in a prior variable?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to figure out why Bash is seemingly evaluating a variable expansion for a variable in which I use a previously defined variable that is using variable expansion. Perhaps there is something else going on here, but what it is, I can't quite figure out.

I define $LATEST_VERSION to take the everything past the last '/' in $LOCATION, the URL I am being redirected to from $LATEST_URL.

At the moment $LATEST_VERSION gets evaluated to the following:

> v0.11.17

This is the code that I am executing:

```
#!/bin/bash
OS=${1:-"linux"}
ARCH=${2:-"arm"}
LATEST_URL="https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/releases/latest"
LOCATION=`curl -I $LATEST_URL | perl -n -e '/^Location: (.*)$/ &&  print "$1\n"'`
LATEST_VERSION=${LOCATION##*/}
VERSION=${3:-$LATEST_VERSION}
DOWNLOAD_URL="https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/release/download/${VERSION}/syncthing-${OS}-${ARCH}-${VERSION}.tar.gz"
echo "DOWNLOAD_URL: ${DOWNLOAD_URL}"
```

Everything is fine and dandy until I `echo "DOWNLOAD_URL: ${DOWNLOAD_URL}"`:

> .tar.gzing-linux-arm-v0.11.17com/syncthing/syncthing/release/download/v0.11.17

If I take out $VERSION from $DOWNLOAD_URL, it looks as expected ($OS and $ARCH are substituted):

> DOWNLOAD_URL: https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/release/download//syncthing-linux-arm-.tar.gz

I tried everything from prepending the strings with `echo -e`, i.e.

```
LATEST_VERSION=`echo -e ${LOCATION##*/}`
VERSION=`echo -e ${3:-$LATEST_VERSION}`
```

to

```
LATEST_VERSION=`basename $LOCATION`
```

and they all give me unexpected output. Is there something that I'm missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: You've probably got CRLF line endings in the data coming off the internet and the carriage returns are screwing things up.  That's why you're seeing `.tar.gz` at the start of the line.

Comment: It's possible the script itself has the DOS line endings; the output seems consistent with each parameter assignment storing a carriage return at the end of the assigned value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a special character called carriage return (ASCII 13, also known as CR or \r) that moves the cursor to the beginning of the line when printed.

HTTP headers are terminated by a carriage return / line feed combo (CR LF).

Your Perl regex (`/^Location: (.*)$/`) strips off the LF (`.` doesn't match newline by default) but keeps the CR.

`LATEST_VERSION` ends up containing `v0.11.17\r` (where `\r` represents the invisible carriage return).

`DOWNLOAD_URL` ends up being `https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/release/download/v0.11.17\r/syncthing-linux-arm-v0.11.17\r.tar.gz` (again using `\r` to represent carriage return), which when printed looks garbled because `\r` moves the cursor back:

```
https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/release/download/v0.11.17
/syncthing-linux-arm-v0.11.17
.tar.gz
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
.tar.gzing-linux-arm-v0.11.17syncthing/release/download/v0.11.17
```

One way to fix this is to change the regex to `/^Location: (.*)\r\n/`, which moves the `\r` out of `$1`.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably got CRLF line endings in the data coming off the internet and the carriage returns (CR) are screwing things up.  They move the printing position to the start of the line without forcing out a newline (LF, or line feed).  That's why you're seeing `.tar.gz` at the start of the line.

If you echo the value of LATEST_VERSION through a program like `od -c`, you'll see a carriage return `\r` at the end.

Your download URL is created from:

```
DOWNLOAD_URL="https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/release/download/${VERSION}/syncthing-${OS}-${ARCH}-${VERSION}.tar.gz"
echo "DOWNLOAD_URL: ${DOWNLOAD_URL}"
```

Showing the segments, you'd see the following three segments overlaid:

```
DOWNLOAD_URL: https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/release/download/v0.11.17\r
/syncthing-linux-arm-v0.11.17\r
.tar.gz
```

leading to the observed output:

```
.tar.gzing-linux-arm-v0.11.17com/syncthing/syncthing/release/download/v0.11.17
```

To fix, you can edit out the carriage return (see [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the Bash manual):

```
LATEST_VERSION=${LATEST_VERSION/$'\r'/}
```